# iOS UIActivityViewController missing Facebook option

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook

I'm using UIActivityViewController in order to show share dialog.
Facebook, Twitter, Flickr are installed but only Faceboook is missing from the menu.

After looking for the same questions I've found that there is a need to add accounts for those in phone settings. Doing this for Facebook solved the problem, however I still do not understand something: only Facebook had this problem Twitter for example only installed and not defined.

Other question is, is it a must to add Facebook account or there is some workaround? I'm not that happy to ask user to do this in order to share something (he may be already signed in to application).

Comment: This is part of the OS. You can't change it. What if the user doesn't have a Facebook account? The only other way to share to Facebook is to create a Facebook app and log the user in to Facebook through your app.

Comment: In case user doesn't have account but has app installed, he may get in to login screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered with this. The answer is yes. At least one signed in Facebook account is required to use "post to facebook" activity shipped with UIActivityViewController.

You might want to create your own UIActivity subclass by replicating native's behavior plus implementing login flow in case if there is not account signed in.

Comment: Yes. Custom UIActivity is too much effort. Sometimes things just can't be simple.